# How can I use 2 domains from different providers in 1 single web host

Tags: dns, cross-domain, hosting, web-hosting, nameservers

I want to split my web hosting into two different websites without the two domains being hosted with the same provider, is it possible?

Currently I'm using 1 of the domains with the web host, but I have another one outside the hosting provider that I want to use with it without being transferred.

I'm using CPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if domain www.A.com is used with the web host use a CNAME Dns record for domain B pointing to www.A.com.